# Trouble matching LDAP entry with multiline regex

Tags: python, regex, ldif

I have multiple log files with LDAP entries and I'm trying to match only the entries that have a createtimestamp during a certain date but capture the whole entry, not just the timestamp. The entries are as follows:

```
dn: ....
otherattr: 
...
createtimestamp: 20130621061525Z
```

The problem is that I am getting all of the entries that come before the one I want as well.

```
dn: ....
otherattr: 
...
createtimestamp: 20121221082545Z

dn: ....
otherattr: 
...
createtimestamp: 20130621061525Z
```

This is the expression:

```
dn_search = re.compile(r'dn: (.*?)createtimestamp: 20130[4-6]\d+?Z', flags=re.M|re.S)
```

I've tried some other expressions but I am either getting only the createtimestamp or unwanted entries. Any ideas?

Comment: Why aren't you grabbing everything, parsing the date into a datetime object and then filtering on that?

Comment: @Ben Yea, that worked. I guess I just had regex stuck in my head. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

## Description

This regex will assume each group of text start with `dn:` and ends with an empty line. It will then capture the entire group of lines, and capture the `createtimestamp` field's value

`^dn:(?=(?:(?!^createtimestamp:|^dn:|^\s*(?:\r|\n\|$)|\Z).)*^createtimestamp:\s*([^\s\r\n]*))(?:(?!^dn:|^\s*(?:\r|\n\|$)|\Z).)*`

[image]

## Python Code example

Link to working example http://repl.it/J0t

**Code**

```
import re

string = """dn: ....
otherattr: 
...
createtimestamp: 20121221082545Z_1

dn: ....
otherattr: 
...
createtimestamp: 20130621061525Z_2
""";

for matchObj in re.finditer( r'^dn:(?=(?:(?!^createtimestamp:|^dn:|^\s*(?:\r|\n\|$)|\Z).)*^createtimestamp:\s*([^\s\r\n]*))(?:(?!^dn:|^\s*(?:\r|\n\|$)|\Z).)*', string, re.M|re.I|re.S):
    print "-------"
    print "matchObj.group(1) : ", matchObj.group(1)
```

**Returns**

```
-------
matchObj.group(1) :  20121221082545Z_1
-------
matchObj.group(1) :  20130621061525Z_2
```

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work in Python, but thanks for the info.

Comment: That was odd, it worked in PHP but not python, Oh well. See updates.

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to parse LDIF by hand. It's not complicated, but things like attribute and name escaping, and line continuations for long lines, will bite you. Use [the LDIF parser from python-ldap](http://www.python-ldap.org/doc/html/ldif.html).

Comment: Thanks for the info on python-ldap.